# Replace from one custom string to another custom string

Tags: php, regex

How can I replace a string starting with 'a' and ending with 'z'?

basically I want to be able to do the same thing as str_replace but be indifferent to the values in between two strings in a 'haystack'.

Is there a built in function for this? If not, how would i go about efficiently making a function that accomplishes it?

Comment: Sounds like something for regexp

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "I really want to replace aFGHJKz with booo";
$new_string = preg_replace('/a[a-zA-z]+z/', 'boo', $string);
echo $new_string;
```

Be wary of the regex, are you wanting to find the first z or last z? Is it only letters that can be between? Alphanumeric? There are various scenarios you'd need to explain before I could expand on the regex.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Answer when I can

Comment: @Rawkode Hey, not that this would match only alphabetic characters between A and Z instead of all symbols which might be an issue.

Comment: Why `'/a[a-zA-z]+z/'`? By doing so you only allow a-z and A-Z chars in your string. `'/A.*Z/'` is better

Comment: As I said in my answer, I'd need to know more about what is being replace and what should be replaced before I can offer a more fitting regex.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with Regular Expression (RegEx for short).
Here is a simple example:

```
$string = 'coolAfrackZInLife';
$replacement = 'Stuff';
$result = preg_replace('/A.*Z/', $replacement, $string);
echo $result;
```

The above example will return `coolStuffInLife`

**A little explanation on the givven RegEx** `/A.*Z/`:
     - The slashes indicate the beginning and end of the Regex;
     - A and Z are the start and end characters between which you need to replace;
     - `.` matches any single charecter
     - `*` Zero or more of the given character (in our case - all of them)
     - You can optionally want to use `+`  instead of `*` which will match only if there is something in between

Take a look at [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) for a simple way to test your RegExs. It also provides short RegEx reference

Answer (score 0):

use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) so you can use regex patterns.

Comment: He already did.. Don't tell me you did read that page in 2 minutes